# Not an answer - flag declined

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

For the [Free Alternative to WebCron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163476/free-alternative-to-webcron/8324426#8324426) question someone has answered:

> webcron.org offer now a timeOut with 3600 sec. This can help you to wait for a long database backup's feedback.

I have considered flagging this as "Not an answer" or "SPAM".

"Not an answer" because the question is about *something but* webcron.org service. Moreover, it does not contain any need of long timeouts.

"SPAM" because it directly references and promotes the service that **is not** desired by the OP.

Being in doubt which flag is better, I have raised a custom flag with description:

> This is not an answer to the question. It rather tries to promote webcron.org, which OP does not want to use.

which has been declined:

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

In my view, this answer does require moderator intervention as it should be removed.

Comment: How about the other answers? Those looks like spam too. There's another answer mentioning webcron, which is upvoted. In the end, the ideal solution is to nuke the question since it's off-topic, but back then, the rule was not this strict.

Comment: I'd definitely go NAA rather than spam. Any suggestion could be considered spam but, since the question stated webcron was no longer free and they wanted a free alternative, I fail to see how the great feature of a 1h timeout has *anything* to do with the cost.

Comment: The question has been deleted now thanks to the meta effect. Yay!